# Should IDataReader::Dispose call IDataReader::Close?

Tags: c#, idatareader

I'm implementing `IDataReader` and I wonder if the implementation of `Dispose` is supposed to call `Close` or not.

Also, should `Close` call `Dispose`?

My guess is that `Close` shouldn't call `Dispose` and `Dispose` *can* call `Close` since AFAIK you should be able to call `Dispose` as many times as you want in any object. But this is just a guess and I'd rather hear an expert's opinion.

Comment: I just noticed it was IDataReader interface vs the Class sorry SLaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Close()` and `Dispose()` should do the same thing (one should call the other).
However, `Close()` does not need to be callable multiple times.

You should inherit the base `DbDataReader` class instead of re-implementing the whole thing yourself; if so, you'll need to override the abstract `Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

`.Dispose()` should do exactly one thing: release unmanaged resources.  Therefore you should call `.Close()` if and only if calling that function is the correct way to release an unmanaged resource.  In this case, I would say that is true (it will release a database connection), and so you should call the function.

Answer (score 1):

They are both almost the same thing except Close can be called more than 1 time without getting an exception.

If you use the object more than once, implement .Close, if only once, implement .Dispose().

Answer (score -1):

`IDataReader` is in interface. It doesn't dictate implementation.

Comment: How come people write documentation for interfaces then?

Comment: Um... In order to document them?

Comment: Document what their implementation is supposed to do?

Comment: Document what all of their implementations are meant to do. That which is not documented is likely not part of the interface (like whether Dispose must call Close or vice versa)